# pull specific table row column data to output in html using php

Tags: php, mysql, text

how do i pull data from my database table and put that data into a readonly textinput in a form for a user to see.

`<input readonly type="text"  name="em1" id="em1"/>`

for this specific field i want to pull the data from a column called wmyt000 in the row of the currently logged in user using a $username variable with session that i created to get the current logged in users username in a table called cash_flow_plan

im using mysql and php

i havnt attempted to try anything yet. i was looking into `mysql_fetch_array` but that wants to display all of the users information for their row.

Comment: Try adding a WHERE clause to your query.

Answer (score 1):

> i havnt attempted to try anything yet.

ya. well, if you had, you'd know that you can do more with it than you think.

if you write a query limiting your results, then you're going to get what you want.

```
$query = "SELECT wmyt000 FROM cash_flow_plan WHERE username = '$username'"

$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);

print_r($row); // now you can see the structure of your array. access it accordingly.
```

Comment: sometimes i can be a little afraid of php thank you for your answer

Comment: so wait, now how do i tell the readonly input field to give me that value?

Comment: updated my answer so you can see how to print the array out and see the exact structure of the result.... at this point, start googling, i just did. :)